# AngularJS There are any short way to call parent scope in this case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

There are any short way to call parent scope in this case (in a controller)?

```
$scope.tables = [];
$scope.newTable = function(){ 
    $scope.tables.push({name:"Table " + ($scope.tables.length+1),cols:[]});
    $scope.selected = $scope.tables.length-1;
};
```

This code should be shorten when there are any shortway to ignore $scope in $scope.newTable. Maybe I didn't know that

Comment: I don't see you calling parent scope here, what is that you want to achieve? BTW: you do not need to pass `$http` to function

Comment: I've read it about 3 times and I still don't know what you're asking.

Comment: You could do `tables = $scope.tables` and then use the reference instead of `$scope.tables`

Comment: Sorry, I copy too many code lines. I just want to ignore $scope when call $scope.newTable

Comment: @user3584125 as the question was edited, I answer to the first one. I assumed you are trying to expose an object using only one $scope affectation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can define an object within the controller, which one you will expose to the scope later on. Something like:

```
var tableHandler = {
    selected: 0,
    list: [],
    newTable: newTable
};

function newTable()
{
    var tableLength = tableHander.list.length;
    var emptyTable = {name: "Table " + (tableLength + 1), cols: []};
    tableHander.list.push(emptyTable);
    tableHandler.selected = tableLength;
}
;

$scope.tableHandler = tableHandler;
```

Then in your html

```
<button ng-click="tableHandler.newTable()"></button>
```

Another example for repetition and selection support:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="table in tableHandler.list" track by $index"
ng-class="{selected: tableHandler.selected === $index}">
{{table.name}}
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, Flavien Volken